# Return reference to this and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, crtp, static-polymorphism

For some syntactic sugar I want to return a reference to `this`, but when inherited, the function should return the type of the child class:

```
class base {
  T &operator!() { return *this; }
};
base b; b = !b;

class child : public base {};
child c; c = !c;
```

Because of the operator, I can't just return the pointer and dynamic_cast it, it has to be a reference.

Is that even possible? Using `decltype(*this)` for T doesn't work, neither does `auto f()->decltype(*this)`, because of `this` (although I don't understand why, in the auto-case)

In Scala you can write something like:

```
template<typename T> class base {
  T &f() { return *this; }
};
class child : public base<child> {};
```

But my g++ won't accept this (not sure if that's bug or just not in the spec?)

Of course there's the explicit way, but I wonder if this can be avoided using C++11 features?

```
class child : public base {
  child &operator!() { base::operator!(); return *this }
};
```

Comment: Please don't override operators in a way which change their fundamental meanings. It's a really bad idea and will lead to confusion and error.

Comment: in this case it's a DSL thing, I use && actually, and even though it doesn't return a bool, it semantically means "and"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CRTP to do this if you're allowed to make `base` a template:

```
template <typename Derived> class Base {
protected:
    Derived& refToThis() {
        return *static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    }
};
```

Note the extra cast here.  The reason this works is that if you have a class like this one:

```
class Subclass: public Base<Subclass> {
    /* ... */
};
```

Then if you call `refToThis` from inside that class, it will call the base class version.  Since the class inherits from `Base<Subclass>`, the instantiated template for `refToThis` will be

```
    Subclass& refToThis() {
        return *static_cast<Subclass*>(this);
    }
```

This code is safe, because the `this` pointer does indeed point to a `Subclass` object.  Moreover, the `static_cast` will ensure that the cast fails at compile-time if the derived class doesn't inherit from `Base` properly, as the pointer type won't be convertible.

The reason that the cast is necessary here is that if you just say

```
template <typename Derived> class Base {
protected:
    Derived& refToThis() {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Then there is a type error in the program, since a `Base` by itself is *not* a `Derived`, and if you could convert a `Base&` into a `Derived&` without any checks you could break the type system.

That said... I wouldn't do this at all.  Overloading `operator!` for this purpose makes the code less readable, and just writing `*this` is so idiomatic that hiding it will make your code much harder to understand.  Using all of this template machinery to avoid something that's common C++ seems misguided.  If you're doing something else before returning the reference that's fine, but this just doesn't seem like a good idea.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, there was some interference in my code that caused an error in the `class Subclass: public Base<Subclass>` line, I feared this was impossible in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do this. There's already a way to do it in the language, `*whatever_pointer_you_want_to_use_this_crazy_operator_upon`. Creating a new way of doing something in the language will just confuse your future maintainers. Is there something *else* you're actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: What I actually want to do is `a << b << c << d` where the `<<` operator is defined in a base class and inherited, however I need the subtype on the left side, unlike ostream